# How to upload videos to you tube from my app?

Tags: ios

I am capturing video from my app, now I want to upload the same video to youtube from my app itself for that I refered the link below but it shows the error "No linked youtube account" but I have Provided Developer key nad client id. https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/tree/

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly have you done? Can you share some code snippets?

Comment: Hi Stunner,This is the link i reffered https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/tree/

Comment: Try this Post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801383/upload-video-on-youtube-from-iphone-app

Answer (score 5):

Below is some of links to guide you...

1.[Upload Videos to YouTube with iPhone custom App](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/)

2.[gdata-objectivec-client](https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/tree/)

3.[Uploading Video with iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243903/790794)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/raviparmar/YoutubeAPI) is WORKING example for uploading video to youtube from ios .

you just need to add DEVELOPER_KEY &  CLIENT_ID in YouTubeTestViewController.m class. Don't forget to up-vote if you find it useful.